# Search and download files via API with Python

Tags: python, json, api

got a question on downloading files via API. I got this code, which searches the file and returns the info on it.

```
import requests
import pprint


token = requests.post("https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token",
                      json={'auth':
                               {'email': 'my_mail',
                                'password':'my_pass'}})

bearer = token.json()['jwt']

data = requests.get('https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/publication/findById/ws859f67m',
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token.json()['jwt']})


pprint.pprint(data.json())
```

But how can I download the file itself with Python? Can you, please, advice the best way or some tutorials on this topic?

The output for the code above will be:

```
[{'agency': ['Agricultural Marketing Service',
             'Livestock, Poultry and Seed Program'],
  'agency_acronym': ['AMS'],
  'contact_email': ['Websupport.lpgmn@ams.usda.gov'],
  'contact_organization': ['Livestock, Poultry, and Grain Market News'],
  'description': ['This report contains the number of metric tons of grains '
                  'inspected and/or weighed for export from January to '
                  'December by region and country of destination. '],
  'division_acronym': ['AMS-LPS'],
  'frequency': ['Not Specified'],
  'id': 'ws859f67m',
  'identifier': ['WA_GR153'],
  'keywords': ['exports', 'weight', 'barley', 'wheat', 'soybeans', 'corn'],
  'resource_type': ['Report'],
  'status': ['Active'],
  'subject': ['Crops and Crop Products:Grains and Oilseeds'],
  'subscribable': 'Yes',
  'title': ['Annual Grains Inspected and/or Wtd for Export by Region and COD']}]
```

Comment: Which file do you want to download? Are you asking how you can write the JSON data to a file after getting it from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests`' response object has `content` which is `bytes` and thus can be used together with `open` in `wb` mode to download file to disk following way:

```
data = requests.get('https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/publication/findById/ws859f67m',
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token.json()['jwt']})
with open('filename.json','wb') as f:
    f.write(data.content)
```

This method can by used with any type of files, not only text files. This will download file as is, if you wish to save `pprint`-ed version you might do so by giving file handle to `pprint.pprint` as `stream` i.e. in place of

```
pprint.pprint(data.json())
```

do

```
with open('pretty.json','w') as f:
    pprint.pprint(data.json(), stream='filename.json')
```

remember to change `filename.json` to what suits your needs.